# Linq query that does left join and group by having count()

Tags: c#, linq

If I have a Rule which has many Criteria and a user selects multiple criteria, how do I write a linq query giving me all the rules where EVERY criteria within that rule exists with the user's selected criteria?

Here is how I'm doing it in SQL currently:

**Tables**

```
rule:
  ruleId int
  categoryId int

ruleCriteria:
  ruleId int,
  criteriaId int

@userCriteria:
  criteriaId int
  categoryId int
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    r.ruleId
FROM dbo.rule r
INNER JOIN dbo.ruleCriteria rc ON r.ruleId= rc.ruleId
LEFT OUTER JOIN @userCriteria uc
        ON rc.criteriaId = uc.criteriaId
        AND r.categoryId = uc.categoryId
GROUP BY r.ruleId
HAVING COUNT(rc.criteriaId) = COUNT(uc.criteriaId)
```

For the linq query, I'll have these objects (more denormalized, but I could put them in the same structure as the tables if that helps):

```
userCriteria:
  criteriaId int
  categoryId int

ruleCriteria:
  ruleId int
  categoryId int
  criteriaId int
```

My goal is the same as the SQL query which is to get a distinct list of matching rules. How would you do it?

Comment: I think expression trees could help in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query generates better SQL than the other one, and it's more direct:

```
from rc in ruleCriterias
group rc by rc.ruleId into rules
where rules.All(rc => userCriterias.Any(uc =>
    uc.criteriaId == rc.criteriaId && uc.categoryId == rc.categoryId))
select rules.Key
```

You should make sure all the columns are `NOT NULL`, because if they aren't, this has to generate extra SQL to check to see if things are null.

Comment: I'm not generating SQL, I just have two collections of objects. I'm trying to get the business logic out of the data layer and into a unit testable function. I like this better though. It's easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Oh, okay. You had a SQL query, so I assumed you were querying a DB. Anyway, would you choose this as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

I played around with some test data in [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) and this is what I came up with.

```
from rc in ruleCriteria
group new { rc.criteriaId, rc.categoryId } by rc.ruleId into rules
where rules.Count() == userCriteria.Count(uc =>
    rules.Contains(new { uc.criteriaId, uc.categoryId }))
select rules.Key
```

Here's the explanation, line-by-line:

1. Get the rules from `ruleCriteria`
2. Group the criteria like `{ criteriaId, categoryId }` by the `ruleId` and save it in `rules`
3. For each whole rule, check to see if the number of matching `userCriteria` is the same as the total number of rules, meaning the user has all the criteria.
4. Select just the key for this group, which is the `ruleId`.

Comment: This looks very promising. I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding (and therefore over simplyfying the problem) maybe the all [.All()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb548541.aspx) method is what you need.

```
var userCriteria = ; //TODO: Build user criteria
var result = context.Rules.Where(r => r.CategoryId == userCriteria.CategoryId
                                   && r.RuleCriteria.All(rc => rc.id == userCriteria.CriteriaId));
```

This will only return rulls where all the containing criteria match your criteria.  I can't guarantee your sql though

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained well enough. userCriteria wouldn't be a single object, it'd be an IEnumerable of UserCriteria objects.